# JPanel does not repaint

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I am working with multiple BufferedImages. The paint function of the JPanel I am using draws currentImg on the JPanel:

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(currentImg, 0, 0, null);
}
```

currentImg is used so I can easily switch the image, it equals normalImg at the beginning.
redImg is a BufferedImage that looks different to normalImg.
Now I want to paint redImg for half a second and then again normalImg.

```
currentImg = redImg;
repaint();
Thread.sleep(1000);
currentImg = normalImg;
repaint();
```

But this code does nothing, the JPanel does not get repainted. This code works though:

```
currentImg = redImg;
repaint();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"test");
Thread.sleep(1000);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"test");
currentImg = normalImg;
repaint();
```

But I do not want to show a message dialog just to repaint it properly.
Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Avoid overriding `paint`, especially of top level containers, use `JComponent` based components and override their `paintComponent` method.  Take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about panting in Swing
2. Always call `super.paintXxx` of what ever paint method you have overriden
3. Don't use `Thread.sleep` from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, this will prevent it from processing new events from the `EventQueue`, including repaint events.
4. Don't modify the UI from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details and [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for a possible solution

And an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28342538/java-swing-timer-and-animation-how-to-put-it-together/28342986#28342986)

Comment: 1. I do not know why I should do this, but `paintComonent` does the same for me, so I changed it
2.  Have not overriden paint anymore
3. Now I use a swing Timer, thanks
I do not understand what you mean with 4.
But it works now. Thank you really much!

Comment: @kaesaecracker try adding a component to the panel you override `paint` on. Then switch that to `paintComponent` and the different should be noticeable.

Comment: @Obicere I do not need any components inside the JPanel, in fact the whole application just uses one JFrame and one JPanel, nothing more :)

Comment: @kaesaecracker It's generaly recommended to override `paintComponent` as it presents the appropriate layer within the paint chain from which custom painting can be performed with affecting anything else. It's also slightly safer if you break the paint chain, as it's much easier to identify the cause of the problem. 4. means that Swing is not thread safe and you should not modify the UI from outside of the main UI thread (the EDT), so using a Thread to solve the problem would be a bad idea

Answer (score 5):

You're freezing your entire application by calling `Thread.sleep(...)` within your paint method and in the Swing event thread. Don't do this. Instead use a Swing Timer and swap a JLabel's Icons from within the Timer.

For example:

[image]

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SwapImages extends JPanel {
   private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 200;
   private static final String SPRITE_PATH = "http://th02.deviantart.net/"
         + "fs70/PRE/i/2011/169/0/8/blue_player_sprite_sheet_by_resetado-d3j7zba.png";
   public static final int SPRITE_ROWS = 6;
   public static final int SPRITE_COLS = 6;
   public static final int SPRITE_CELLS = 35;

   private JLabel label = new JLabel();
   private List<ImageIcon> iconList = new ArrayList<ImageIcon>();
   private int iconIndex = 0;

   public SwapImages() throws IOException {
      URL imgUrl = new URL(SPRITE_PATH);
      BufferedImage mainImage = ImageIO.read(imgUrl);

      for (int i = 0; i < SPRITE_CELLS; i++) {
         int row = i / SPRITE_COLS;
         int col = i % SPRITE_COLS;
         int x = (int) (((double) mainImage.getWidth() * col) / SPRITE_COLS);
         int y = (int) ((double) (mainImage.getHeight() * row) / SPRITE_ROWS);
         int w = (int) ((double) mainImage.getWidth() / SPRITE_COLS);
         int h = (int) ((double) mainImage.getHeight() / SPRITE_ROWS);
         BufferedImage img = mainImage.getSubimage(x, y, w, h);
         ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
         iconList.add(icon);
      }
      add(label);
      label.setIcon(iconList.get(iconIndex));
      new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new TimerListener()).start();
   }

   private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
         iconIndex++;
         iconIndex %= iconList.size();
         label.setIcon(iconList.get(iconIndex));
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      SwapImages mainPanel = null;
      try {
         mainPanel = new SwapImages();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         System.exit(-1);
      }

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("SwapImages");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: I do not change the ImageIcon of a JLabel, but the BufferedImage painted on a JPanel

Comment: @kaesaecracker: I understand, but if all you're doing is swapping the image, sometimes it's easier to do it with an image icon, especially if you're doing animation.

Comment: @HovercaftFullOfEels I see how that could be useful, but I would need to create those ImageIcons first, and I do not know the resolution the application has

Comment: @HovercaftFullOfEels I have a similar problem and I also solved it with a Swing Timer, but when the jPanel loses the focus it restarts the animation. Can you briefly explain why?