# The image's event handler shows error in Java GUI

Tags: java, image, swing, random, awt

I've created the `r Jbutton` and inserted an image into the `c JButton`. All I want to do is add an event handler to the `r JButton` that when it is clicked the image in `c button`  to be changed as specified in the method `roll()`. But it shows an error inside the handler class for line with `r.roll`. Can someone show me how to add the handler  into the `r JButton` in a way that when the `r JButton` is clicked the method roll executes and the image is changed?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.imageio.*;

public class Background extends JFrame{      
  private Random ran;
  private int value;
  private JButton r;
  private JButton c;

  public Background ()
  {
    super("title");
    ran = new Random();
    value = nextValue() ;
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    r=new JButton("ROLL ");
    r.setForeground(Color.WHITE);//ndryshon ngjyren e shkrimit
    r.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    add(r,BorderLayout.SOUTH);    

    Icon i=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("1.png"));
    Icon im=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("2.png"));

    c= new JButton(i);
    add(c);

    thehandler hand=new thehandler(this);//konstruktori i handler merr nje instance te Background
    r.addActionListener(hand);
    c.addActionListener(hand);
  }

  private int nextValue() {
    return Math.abs(ran.nextInt()) % 6 + 1 ;
  }

  public void roll() {
    value = nextValue() ;
    if (value==1){
      Icon i=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("1.png"));
      c= new JButton(i);
      add(c);
    } else if(value==2){
      Icon im=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("2.png"));
      c= new JButton(im);
      add(c);
    }

    repaint() ;
  }

  public int getValue() {
    return value ;
  }

  private class thehandler implements ActionListener{
    private Background m ;

    thehandler(Background thisone) {
      m = thisone ;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
      m.roll();
      r.roll();//ERROR  
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {       
    Background  d = new Background() ;
    d.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    d.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    d.setSize(700,500);
    d.setVisible(true);  
  }
}
```

Comment: Please include the error every time you post a question. Somebody worked really hard to create meaningful, useful error handlign and messages in Java and it's a shame to overlook them. My guess is it's a `NullPointerException` because you didn't initialize your variable `r`.

Comment: Ok the error is the method roll is undefined.But can you please show me a way to add a handler to the jbutton which makes this image to change?Thanks

Comment: `r` is a `JButton`. It does not have a `roll()` method. Use [setIcon()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setIcon%28javax.swing.Icon%29) if you want to change a buttons icon.

Comment: @kiheru Ok i did this:if (value==1){
 Icon i=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("1.png"));
c.setIcon(i);
}                                                                                                                                        but how can I add this handler to the r jbutton?So that when r jbutton is clicked the icon is changed as above?Tanks

Comment: these questions are out there why dont you do a little work of your own - you have covered so with every little question

Comment: I'm not sure what you're attempting to do, but: you can simply call `roll()` in the action listener - and `roll()` should not create new buttons, but call `r.setIcon()` with the appropriate new icon.

Comment: @kiheru what i'm attepmting to do: when the r button is clicked the image in the cbutton to change from 1.png to 2.png depending from the value like this                                                                                                              public void roll() {
    value = nextValue() ;
    if (value==1){
      Icon i=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("1.png"));
      c= new JButton(i);
      add(c);
    } else if(value==2){
      Icon im=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("2.png"));
      c= new JButton(im);
      add(c);
    }... The value is a random nr from 1-6.

Comment: @gpasch i'm working all day with this,but no result

Comment: Verify that the images are been loaded, `BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("1.png"))`, this will throw an `IOException` so you will need to wrap in a `try-catch` block.

Comment: Why are you creating new buttons in the `roll` method??  The [previous answer to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34936103/error-when-adding-event-handler-into-a-jbutton-to-repaint-the-image-injava-gui/34936799?noredirect=1#comment57635226_34936799) clearly showed using `setIcon` on the current instance of the button.  Try using `c.setText(Integer.toString(value))` in the `roll` method to verify they are been updated (and get rid of the button creation within the method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you creating new instance of `JButton` in `roll`? You just need to change the icon of the buttons which are already displayed on the screen

This...

```
public void roll() {
    value = nextValue() ;
    if (value==1){
        Icon i=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("1.png"));
        c= new JButton(i);
        add(c);
    } else if(value==2){
        Icon im=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("2.png"));
        c= new JButton(im);
        add(c);
    }

    repaint() ;
}
```

should be...

```
public void roll() {
    value = nextValue() ;
    Icon i = null;
    if (value==1){
        i=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("1.png"));
    } else if(value==2){
        i=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("2.png"));
    }
    c.setIcon(i);
}
```

`setIcon` is a bound field, which means that it will automatically generate a `repaint` request of it's own.

If the images are not been updated then it's likely that your images aren't been loaded, you can test this in two ways, first, you can set the text of  the buttons

```
public void roll() {
    value = nextValue() ;
    c.setText(Integer.toString(value));
    Icon i = null;
    if (value==1){
        i=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("1.png"));
    } else if(value==2){
        i=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("2.png"));
    }
    c.setIcon(i);

    repaint() ;
}
```

and second, you should be using `ImageIO.read` to load the resources, for example...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Background extends JFrame {

    private Random ran;
    private int value;
    private JButton r;
    private JButton c;

    public Background() {
        super("title");
        ran = new Random();
        value = nextValue();
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        r = new JButton("ROLL ");
        r.setForeground(Color.WHITE);//ndryshon ngjyren e shkrimit
        r.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        add(r);

        try {
            BufferedImage die = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("1.png"));
            c = new JButton(new ImageIcon(die));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        add(c);

        thehandler hand = new thehandler(this);//konstruktori i handler merr nje instance te Background
        r.addActionListener(hand);
        c.addActionListener(hand);
    }

    private int nextValue() {
        return Math.abs(ran.nextInt()) % 6 + 1;
    }

    public void roll() {
        value = nextValue();
        c.setText(Integer.toString(value));
        URL path = null;
        if (value == 1) {
            path = getClass().getResource("1.png");
        } else if (value == 2) {
            path = getClass().getResource("2.png");
        }
        try {
            BufferedImage die = ImageIO.read(path);
            c.setIcon(new ImageIcon(die));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    private class thehandler implements ActionListener {

        private Background m;

        thehandler(Background thisone) {
            m = thisone;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            m.roll();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Background d = new Background();
        d.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        d.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        d.setSize(700, 500);
        d.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This my throw a `NullPointerException`, which would mean that Java can't find your images.  Based on your code, you images must be stored within the same package as your class

Have a look at [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more details about `ImageIO`

The problem with this...

```
r.roll();//ERROR
```

is `JButton` has not `roll` method