# Java - Small animation for yahtzee - changing images

Tags: java, image, animation

I would like to add some kind of animation to my current Yahtzee project in Java. This should actually only consist of the fact that several pictures are displayed in a mess. So in my case the dice that show the numbers between 1 and 6. The output is supposed to happen later on my main screen on a JLabel - had only read that this should work with threads somehow, but since I am new, I have no idea about that.

```
public void wuerfelAnzeigen(){        
    jPanel1.removeAll();
    jPanel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,5));
    jPanel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(83,400));

    for(Wuerfel wuerfel: becher.getAlWuerfel()){           
        jPanel1.add(new WuerfelLabel(wuerfel, alBilder));
    }        
    jPanel1.repaint();

}
```

Comment: Do you mean something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28342538/java-swing-timer-and-animation-how-to-put-it-together/28342986#28342986)?

Comment: That's very special and I haven't really learned how to read the most important things yet. Could you kindly explain to me what this might look like? So what do I have to consider to make this work like the case you sent me? I have the six pictures of the respective numbers - which are then simply randomly run through and at the end should be replaced by the already existing edition. Thank you.